# Iterate dataframe and assign value to each row- I get the same value while I want different ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the library isbntools to assign book titles to isbns. From a dataframe that has isbns, I want to create a column named title and assign the title to the corresponding isbn. Problem is I get the same title.

Example dataframe:

`isbn`

`01234567`

Desidred output

`isbn, title`
`01234567, Curious George`

Code:

```
from isbntools.app import *

for i in range(len(df_all['isbn'])):
    for isbnz in df_all['isbn']:
        meta_dict = meta(isbnz, service='goob')
        title = meta_dict['Title']
        df_all.iloc[i, df['Title'][i]]
```

I tried with iloc but it seems it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# isbnlib is already installed as a dependency of isbntools
import isbnlib

def get_title(isbn):
    try:
        return isbnlib.meta(isbn)['Title']
    except isbnlib.NotValidISBNError:
        return None

df['Title'] = df['isbn'].astype(str).map(get_title)
```

```
>>> df
            isbn                  Title
0       01234567                   None
1  9780007525546  The Lord Of The Rings
```